# Azure CLI environment variables from ~/.azure/config

Tags: bash, azure, environment-variables, azure-cli

I'm trying to configure some default values for the Azure CLI on a server. The documentation here reads that I can define these in ~/.azure/config and have them loaded as environment variables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration

I can't seem to get this work. Do I need to explicitly tell the Azure CLI to load these into the environment, or have a misread the documentation?

Here's a script where I'm attempting to use the **storage** section **account** variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=$(date +"%F")

az storage copy -s ./test_dir/ -d https://${AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net/backup/${current_date} --recursive
```

Comment: Put the complete URL in quotations. Also, I would try and use the complete path when specifying test_dir

Comment: How do you try the environment variables? Provide all the steps you did.

Comment: That's just it; there are no more steps. I've defined the variables I want in ~/.azure/config and when I access them in a script, like above, they're not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the document wants to show you.

1. Command-line parameters
2. Environment variables
3. Values in the configuration file or set with az configure

The list above shows the three ways to set the Azure CLI configuration. I think you configured using the third way, but use the wrong way to achieve it. In this way, you need to configure the config file by adding this:

```
[storage]
account='account_name'
key='xxxx'
```

And then use the CLI command like this:

```
az storage copy -s ./test_dir/ --destination-container backup --destination-blob $current_date --recursive
```

Then the command will automatically find the destination account name and key in the config file.

By the way, if you want to use the second way, you need to set all the environment variables yourself.